# Key binding to select the current paragraph

Tags: key-bindings, cursor-motions, visual-mode

I'm using the following key binding to visually select the current paragraph.

```
nnoremap <leader>v }kV{j
```

Is works as follows:

1. `}` Move below the current paragraph.
2. `k` Move one line up.
3. `V` Start line-based visual selection.
4. `{` Move above the current paragraph.
5. `j` Move one line down.

This works well except for the last paragraph in the file. If there is no empty line below the current paragraph `}` stops at the last line inside the paragraph. The following `k` results in the last line of the paragraph not being included in the selection. The same problem occurs with the very first paragraph in the file.

How can I make this key binding to also work for paragraphs at the top of bottom of the document?

Is there a text object for this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See:

- [`:h ip`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#ip)
- [`:h ap`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#ap)

You are looking for the built in `vip`.

Also, [`:h text-objects`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#text-objects) is a good start to find the text objects you are looking for.

**Edit** To address your comment: to move the cursor to one end or the other end of the current visual selection you can simply use `o` in visual mode.

[`:h v_o`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/visual.txt.html#v_o)

Comment: Awesome, I tried `vi{` but not `vip`. Can you think of a way to make the cursor end up at the start of the paragraph as in my key binding, rather than at the end?

Comment: @danijar `o` in visual mode moves the cursor to the other end of the current selection, so `vipo`

Comment: Learned a lot, thanks. May not even need a macro for that.

Comment: @danijar Indeed that is clearly not worth a macro nor a custom mapping :)

Comment: This command serves to select the current SQL query if the query is separated from other queries by carriage returns